# What does the swearword "Gimp" mean?

Tags: american-english, offensive-language

In the movie `Hick` the girl is in a car with a farmer, after a while something happens and the girl calls the man a `gimp` and the man gets really angry about it. What does it mean?

According to [this](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/gimp) site it would mean `moron` or `idiot`, but the man got really upset by being called that so I think it might be worse.

Comment: Is the man disabled in any way? http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gimp

Comment: Please tell us the exact quote. Without context, we cannot answer this question.

Comment: Did you look it up? -- in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gimp), for instance, the second definition?

Comment: @Hank Yes, he has a bad leg and is crippled.

Comment: @NVZ Her: "Well is my mouth too big in general or do I talk too much?" Him: "Well, both" her: "Yeah, well what do you know anyways? Gimp..".

Comment: @StoneyB Yes I did, but the definition did not really make any sense to me.

Comment: @Jeff How does the definition "a physically disabled person", not make any sense? It's a slang word that is offensive to someone who is physically disabled.

Comment: @Hank It is, but I can not accept your answer as an answer because you put it in the comment section. If you could please post it as an answer I will flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Jeff I appreciate it, but it's not necessary to answer officially. As it currently stands, this post is not only off-topic for lack of context (added in comments but not in post), but it's also available through commonly available resources. An answer is not needed.

Comment: I would not describe it as a "swearword"; though I'm hard pressed to characterise what are swearwords and what aren't. I think the difference is that a swearword is potentially offensive to anybody who hears it, whereas an epithet like that is primarily  offensive only to the person it's applied to. Hmm. Haven't thought about this before.

Comment: It's not a swear word in the sense of "fuck" or "shit", in that you wouldn't use the term to express your displeasure on having a flat tire or some such.  It is offensive, however, when used to refer to a person with a disability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Gimp* is someone who has a limp, an uneven walk due to a leg or hip problem. The 'swear word' part comes from using the word as a label and barking the word at someone. The word is not polite when referring to a third party, an insult when addressing some with a limp, because it is name calling.

Compare the tender Les Miserable lyric "He is only a boy" with ordering an adult man around by addressing him as "Boy."

Comment: Though it's most often used to refer to difficulty walking, the term might also be applied to someone with a disfigured arm or some other physical disability.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a swear word, exactly. It is a pejorative, meant to be insulting based on the person belonging to an undesirable group.  Racial epithets fall in much the same category.

And yes, it means someone who is lame.